# how to parse json data encoded with square brackets

Tags: java, grails

I'm using mailgun and the webhook sends a post to my server with json data in the following format.  I am not familiar with how to parse this type of json request that doesn't use curly brackets.  I'm not sure what the format is called to search for a solution.

I need to parse the return string and be able to access the elements as json['Received']

```
[["Received", "by luna.mailgun.net with SMTP mgrt 8778766572977; Sat, 01 Feb 2014 22:55:12 +0000"
 ["X-Envelope-From", "<person@domain.com>"
 ["Return-Path", "<person@domain.com>"
 ["Received", "from some data here Sat, 01 Feb 2014 14:55:09 -0800 (PST)"
 ["Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=\"us-ascii\""
 ["Mime-Version", "1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 6.6 \\(1510\\))"
 ["Subject", "Re: Hello world"
 ["From", "AT <you@you.com>"
 ["In-Reply-To", "<20140201225343.7954.82391@mydomain.com>"
 ["Date", "Sat, 1 Feb 2014 16:55:08 -0600"
 ["Content-Transfer-Encoding", "7bit"
 ["Message-Id", "<86C3EA0C-5D9B-4BFA-A76B-54CFC3238714@you.com>"
 ["References", "<20140201225343.7954.82391@mydomain.com>"
 ["To", "messages@mydomain.com"
 ["X-Mailgun-Incoming", "Yes"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not JSON indeed.

You can parse it e.g. like this.

If you have this file saved as UTF-8 make sure it is saved with
no BOM otherwise this program below will produce an additional
first line which looks like empty but is not.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String fn = "C:\\Various\\input.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fn), "UTF8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String str = null;
        while ((str = br.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(str);
        }
        br.close();
        String z = sb.toString();
        String[] arr = z.split("\\[+|\\]+|, \"");
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i].trim();
            if (!arr[i].isEmpty()){
                if (arr[i].charAt(0) == '"'){
                    arr[i] = arr[i].substring(1);
                }
                if (arr[i].charAt(arr[i].length() - 1) == '"'){
                    arr[i] = arr[i].substring(0, arr[i].length() - 1);
                }
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```